# Appending data from several url JSON calls - into one NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

So, i have a loop where i repeatedly call an url, which returns contacts in JSON format.

Since i call the url more than once, i want to add it all up, an ultimately end up with a NSDictionary, containing contacts for all the url calls.

What i'm doing now, is appending the data for each iteration:

```
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                             returningResponse:nil error:nil];
[data appendData:response];
```

---

and when the loop is over i try to make it into a NSDictionary:

```
// Loop over - create Dict from all the data. 
NSDictionary *JSONDataFinal = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                         options:0 error:&error2];
```

I get an error: "garbage at end" and believe the approach is wrong, since it doesn't know how to put data from each consecutive call into the same key, and not create a key for each call.

Should i create a Dictionary for each iteration - and combine them in the end?

Comment: Go to json.org and *really* study the JSON syntax.  Then you will understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: (Note that a dictionary is not the object to use to collect sequential data.  You should be using an array.  Only if you're "sorting" the data as you receive it, or "annotating" it somehow to identify which set is which would a dictionary make sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create different dictionary for each json data and store in main array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrAllContacts = [NSMutableArray array];
//here arrJsonURL which stores all url for contacts
for(int i=0; i<[arrJsonURL count]; i++)
{
   //create request
   ...............

   NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                             returningResponse:nil error:nil];
  [data appendData:response];

  NSError *error = nil;
  //get dictionary from json data
  NSDictionary *dictContact = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

  [arrAllContacts addObject:dictContact];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can append data to a NSMutableDictionary after each call.

```
NSMutableDictionary* jsonDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for (...) {
            ...
            NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                     returningResponse:nil error:nil];
            NSDictionary *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                          options:0 error:&error2];
            [jsonDict addEntriesFromDictionary:JSONData];
        }
```